# How can I run 1 and any other bot command in discord.py?

Tags: python, background, command, bots, discord

I was wondering if there was a way to run the contents of 1 bot command (which has an endless loop) in the background while the user can still use different command(s). I want the first command to run while the user in the discord server can still use the message command and see a printed message. The code is below. Thanks.

```
@bot.command() #bot command for printing a random string every 360 seconds
async def initiateauto(ctx):
    count=0
    await ctx.send(jokerQuotes[random.randint(0,14)])

    while True: #timer
        print(count)
        time.sleep(1)
        count=count+1
        if count==3600:
            await ctx.send(jokerQuotes[random.randint(0,14)])
            count=0

@bot.command() #another bot command that prints a message
async def message(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello")
```

Comment: BTW: just use `random.choice(jokerQuotes)`. Also, since a `sleep` is needed inside the loop anyway, it would be simpler to just sleep for the entire hour all at once and skip the second-counting logic.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-run-something-in-the-background) links to an [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py) for this sort of thing.

Comment: You probably don't want a command to do the `create_task` part, since then multiple uses of the command would increase the frequency of quotes appearing. Consider instead having the command set a flag that enables the task to do its thing.